# Python how to pass list of argument pair in executor.map

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, arguments

What I have:

```
ids = [1,2,3...]
dates = ['a', 'b', 'c'...]

def f(id, date):
  print(f'{id} - {date}')
```

What I intend to do:
Run f in multithreads with every combination of id, dates as arguments

Expected output:

```
1 - a
1 - b
1 - c
2 - a
2 - b
2 - c
3 - a
3 - b
3 - c 
...
```

This obviously doesn't work

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    executor.map(f, ids, dates)
```

This doesn't work either and looks clumsy:
first use loops to build a list of  arguments combo like

```
args = [[1,a][1,b][1,c]
        [2,a],[2,b],[2,c]
        ...
       ]
```

and pass it to f:

```
    executor.map(f, args)
```

or

```
    executor.map(f, *args)
```

either failed

Or redesign f so it takes only one argument?

There must a nice way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) will iterate all iterables in parallel. It won't try to find all combinations:

> If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel.

A simple fix would be to use `itertools.product`. There is no nicer **and** readable way I can think of:

Change your function to:

```
def f(t):
  id, date = t
  print(f'{id} - {date}')
```

then:

```
import itertools
...
    executor.map(f, itertools.product(ids, dates))
```

Comment: just realise my question actually is how to pass multiple arguments in map(), after some research I found another solution could be  functools.partial. Thank you.